# Create a sidebar menu animate with bottom bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, toolbar

After much research, I still could not find the solution...

Is it possible to manage a sidebar with a button at the bottom of the screen ?

I just implemented `AMSlideMenu` lib to my project. However, this system used the navigation bar (top bar). How I can use a button on the toolbar to manage (display and hide) my sidebar?

Otherwise, is it possible to move a navigation bar on the bottom screen ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is in the documentation for this component [here](https://github.com/SocialObjects-Software/AMSlideMenu).

Simply create a toolbar and put it wherever you want, then set up the target actions to call one of the following methods:

```
- (void)openLeftMenu;
- (void)openLeftMenuAnimated:(BOOL)animated;
- (void)openRightMenu;
- (void)openRightMenuAnimated:(BOOL)animated;
- (void)closeLeftMenu;
- (void)closeLeftMenuAnimated:(BOOL)animated;
- (void)closeRightMenu;
- (void)closeRightMenuAnimated:(BOOL)animated;
```

As for the navigation bar, I would not recommend putting it on the bottom. This goes against iOS design principles and is unexpected. Perhaps you want to put a regular UIToolBar on bottom, that would be typical.